# MatSort and MatPaginator not being initialized using @ViewChild and ngAfterViewInit if inside *ngIf

Tags: angular-material, angular-ng-if, mat-table, viewchild

I am using a mat table with paginator and sort within an `*ngIf`. The table data is retrieved using an API.

This is the component's typescript code:

```
export class UserPermissionAdminComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {

  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<UserPermission> = new MatTableDataSource<UserPermission>();
  columnsToDisplay: string[] = ['id', 'name'];

  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: false }) sort!: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: false }) paginator!: MatPaginator;

  constructor(private userPermService: UserPermissionService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userPermService.getAllUserPermissions()
      .subscribe(recvPerms => this.dataSource.data = recvPerms);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    console.log(this.dataSource.sort);
  }

  applyFilter(event: Event): void {
    const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
  }

}
```

And this is the component's template:

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Permisiuni utilizatori</h2>

  <ng-container *ngIf="dataSource.data.length; then existingPermissions; else noPermissions">
  </ng-container>

  <ng-template #existingPermissions>
    <div>
      <div class="filter-container">
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label>Cautare</mat-label>
          <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event)" placeholder="Ex: READ" #input />
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      
      <div class="table-container mat-elevation-z8">
        <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
          <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> ID </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let permission"> {{permission.id}} </td>
          </ng-container>
          <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Denumire permisiune </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let permission"> {{permission.name}} </td>
          </ng-container>
          <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></tr>
          <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let rowData; columns: columnsToDisplay"></tr>
        </table>
        <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]"></mat-paginator>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-template>

  <ng-template #noPermissions>
    <div>
      <span class="notification">Nu a fost gasita nicio permisiune utilizator.</span>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

The issue is that sorting and pagination do not work (the console.log also lists that `this.sort` is `undefined`). The table contains all the data on a single page. Filtering also works.

Answer (score 3):

I have managed to fix the issue by adding setters to the paginator and sort:

```
@ViewChild(MatSort, { static: false }) set sort(val: MatSort) {
    if (val) {
      this.dataSource.sort = val;
    }
  }

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: false }) set paginator(val: MatPaginator) {
    if (val) {
      this.dataSource.paginator = val;
    }
  }
```

However, the code now works even without `ngAfterViewInit`. Can someone please explain how and why this works?